# Rxjs observable subscribe json, root parameter?

Tags: json, rxjs, observable, subscribe

i have a simple subscribe to observable in a function:

```
public MyGet () {
   let results={};
   this.http.get("myfile.json").map(res => res.json()).subscribe(
          output => { 
            results=output.clients; // clients is the root of json file
          },
          /* etc */
```

The json file "myfile.json" is:

```
{
"clients" : [
    { "name":"X",
      "age":"34" },
    { "name": "Y",
      "age": "41" },
    /* etc */
```

I want "clients" as a parameter in the function MyGet:

```
public MyGet (json_root: any){
   let results={};
   this.http.get("myfile.json").map(res => res.json()).subscribe(
          output => { 
            results=output.HERE; // HERE = json_root
          },
          /* etc */
```

So i can call:

```
MyGet("clients")
```

I don't understand how to write the json_root in HERE

Comment: I don't really understand how the result can be used. But for the `output.HERE` you can do `output[json_root]`.

Comment: My example is a semplification, but with "clients" does works. The idea is to have the root of the json file as a parameter. I tried output[json_root], does not work.

Comment: ok, weird. I meant where did you call your results or where did you display it ?

Comment: This is not the point, is complicated to explain, and i can't change this structure. The point is that with static "output.clients" does works, with the dynamic parameter "output.json_root" does not work. I don't understand which syntax I have to use, "output. ?"

Comment: Ok, this is weird, output[json_root] should work, see here: https://jsfiddle.net/ftb33mv0/1/

Comment: Now [json_root]  works..i don't know why yesterday did not work, i'm sure the syntax was the same. Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can split your function.

```
  public MyGet (): Observable<any>{
   return  this._http.get("myfile.json").map(res => res.json());
  }
  ....
  private json_root: any;

  public callAndSubscrive(json_key: string){
    this.MyGet().subscribe(output => {this.json_root = output[json_key]; console.log(output)});
  }
```

Comment: why? My problem is that i don't understand which syntax does works. "clients" is the root of the json file, as you can see in the example. Now i have a static "output.clients" and i need a dynamic parameter "output.json_root" (where json_root is the "clients" in the call fo the function). But with "output.json_root" does not work. In the definition of the MyGet(json_root: any) it says "unused parameter"

Comment: Ok I see. In that case what people are are saying above _output[json_root]_ should work. However do a console.log of output and json_root and verify that output and json_root are what you are expecting. If output is an object like _var obj = {a: 'aa', b: 'bb'}_ then _obj['a']_ is correct to retrieve the value.

Comment: Now [json_root]  works..i don't know why yesterday did not work, i'm sure the syntax was the same. Thanks!!